# Do docker containers have time synchronized between each-other?

Tags: docker, time, synchronization

I am running a few containers connected to each other in a network, and they are running some programs that output logfile with timestamps. The containers are all in the same host.

If two containers output log lines with the same timestamp, does that mean the logged event happened at the same time in both? And vice-versa, if an event happens at the same time in both containers, will the same timestamp be output?

Comment: Your containers will use the time from the host system. So if your two host systems are not synchronized, containers aren't also...

Comment: @Salem The containers are all on the same host. Does that mean the answer is yes?

Comment: Then unless there is something weird between the containers (ex different timezone por logging config),  then they should have the same time

Comment: To repeat other comments, yes, they will have the same time, and they will likely have the same timezone, but they may not have the same timezone as the host. In my limited experience, I find that the containers I've been running default to UTC, no matter what the timezone is of the host. I prefer to have the tz match, so I volume map /etc/localtime and set the TZ environment variable to the TZ of the host.